# QHostAddress установть адрес IPv4 в dynDNS

Tags: c++, qt

```
udpSocket4.writeDatagram("work!", QHostAddress("35.22.112.45"), 7878);
```

В этом случае данные отправляются

```
udpSocket4.writeDatagram("work!", QHostAddress("375331111111.dyndns.mts.by"), 7878);
```

В этом случае нет, как правильно записать QHostAddress DynDNS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QHostAddress`, [как написано](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qhostaddress.html#details) в его документации не выполняет DNS-запросов, для этого надо использовать [`QHostInfo::fromName()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qhostinfo.html#fromName):

```
QHostInfo hi = QHostInfo::fromName("375331111111.dyndns.mts.by");
assert (!hi.error());
assert (hi.addresses.size > 0);
QHostAddress ha = hi.addresses().first();
```

Стоит помнить, что `QHostInfo::fromName()` — блокирующий вызов; если нужен неблокирующий варианта стоит использовать [`QHostInfo::lookupHost()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qhostinfo.html#lookupHost).

---

Ну и помимо прочего стоит проверить, что адрес правильный...